# how to select a column and 3 columns after it in mysql, Automatically

Tags: php, mysqli

Say I have a table like this :
[image: a booking table]

Say I want to select a column from id = 4 and date=2014/2/14
I must say mysql like this:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost",'root','','myDatabase');    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=`4`";

$result=  $db->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

$time = $row->"2014/2/14";

echo $time;

}
```

And this will result like this:
   9-10AM

So far it's OK with no problem
But say I want to select 6 coumun after 2014/2/14 too!!
every time I select an id an a date like 2014/2/14 , I want to show 6 day after 2014/2/14

I mean I expect result to be like this(continuing my example):
**bold**

```
9-10AM

8-10AM

9-10AM

6-7PM
```

for god sake, please don bit around the bushes
see:
[image]
how to do this?

Comment: You should change your tables' structure. Having dates as column names is terrible idea.

Comment: Aha, so how I must make a table like this?
every doctor in my site, can have an id and some avalable times "in a day" , and its obvious that every day that goes by, doctor will put new avalable hours in new days
and I want to show that avalable day and hours in it, in my site, so a patient can click on a hour and book that hour from that specific doctor
how to do that?

Comment: +1 u_mulder this is VERY bad pratice and will result in loads of issues on the long run. Why do you need to store dates as column and row in your tables ? Why can you not generate those dates and time (times being everyday teh same I assume) straight from php into the form, and then store the chosen dates and time into your table. This way not only you won't have times and dates store in columns and rows, but you will also be able to associate a patient id to every appointment. So you'd have Columns : Doctors, Rows : Patients, date times as content (well formated ofc, eg : unix time)

Comment: A database you are using is called 'relational' on purpose. You have to create a system of interconnected tables. See other comments for details. Also, avoid creating empty rows for the would-be available days. But add empty cells at the application level, when drawing table.

Comment: For sector sake, have a look on ZOCDOC.com , in there, search for a doctor, in result , you'll see every doctor has some avalable hours which you can click on , and book that time, how's that? what can I do :(

Comment: I'm completely scrwed:(
I don know what to do anymore
:(

Comment: I see you are a doctor. That's great beacuse I am caught right in the middle of surgery operation I am doing myself. It's funny, you know, to do one occasionally. So by an by I got quite entangled in that internal stuff of the body. Actually I'm completely scrwed and know not what to do anymore. You surely can help me to sort things out and finish the job.

Comment: consult ur team, re create your database structure. if u r home alone then its a bad day, bcoz ur situation is not clear & for such problems it needs full retouch and SO is not a place for that

Comment: For one thing, you can't wrap your `WHERE id=`4` in backticks. Use single quotes `WHERE id='4'` @xe4me which is one of the causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a 75K trolling user (who now covered his tracks by deleting all comments) thinks it is wise to first teach you about complicated things like SQL injection and how to prevent this here we go. So better first read through these links you won't learn anything since it expects you to know the basics but we do not seem to care here in this community.

http://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/Practical-SQLi-Identification.pdf

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Alex.Orso/papers/halfond.viegas.orso.ISSSE06.pdf

http://web.archive.org/web/20070928163708/http://www.ngssoftware.com/papers/advanced_sql_injection.pdf

https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Salgado-SQLi-Optimization-and-Obfuscation-Techniques-WP.pdf

While we are learning already about injection it might be wise to know how to optimize your database too since you are talking about large numbers.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/files/presentations/UC2005-Advanced-MySQL-Performance-Optimization.pdf

And a comprehensive guide to working with date and time since you want to work with date and time.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/mysqlian/chapter/ch06.pdf

(believe me, i would have written all these guides down here for future reference but that would take to much time, so forgive me that i just post the links).

Now you are probably a view years older and know pretty much about MySQL, yet i leave my original answer here for others that might bump into the same problem. You have to look into normalization of your database. Mysql can look for time and dates if they are records inside a table. Not if they are column headers.

name your columns like: ID - date - time

Now you can search for a certain time with BETWEEN like this:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN  (yourdate) AND (yourdate + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This will result in picking all records from the date you select plus 7 days.

-edit-

As for your comment, name your tables like ID - doctor - date - time

Now if you want to see all doctors availability in the comming week between 9:00 and 12:00 do:

```
$doctorQuery = mysql_query("SELECT doctor FROM theTable WHERE date BETWEEN  (NOW()) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND date TIME 9:00:00 AND 12:00:00");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($doctorQuery))
{
    echo $result['doctor']; //you can output it here already.
    $resultarray[] = $result; //or store it for later in a 3 dimensional array.
}

foreach ($resultArray = $singleRow)
{
    echo $singleRow['doctor']; //And output it whenever you want.
}
```

Forgive me, i'm  little rusty and this all is not tested. But this should sent you in the right direction. Please for your own sake, believe us and do not create collumns with dates as headers. This will cause problems later on, one reason is, in two years from now you would have added 730 columns to your table. Of course you could use the dates from my table to output them as headers on your website to make it humanly readable.

-Another edit-
As for you latest comment you probably need a table structure like this:

table for doctors and there info:
[doctorID]-[doctorName]-[doctorInfo]-[LinkToPicture]

Here you fill in a single row for every doctor you have.

Table for there work times:

[timeID]-[doctorID]-[date]-[workhours]

doctorID is a link key, or foreign key which tells the table to which doctor this row belongs. Here fill in the date and time the doctor works. You can insert as many records as you want for each doctor.